# Can't retrieve approval status in Globally Reusable Workflow (Approval - Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow

For day's i am trying to implement the following in one of the standard, out of the box, Globally Reusable Workflow with Sharepoint Designer 2010:

If Current Item:Approval Status not equals 0:#Approved
   Start Approval Workflow Task process on Current Item with Parameter:Approvers
Else
   //Nothing

This is to prevent that a workflow is started if the item is already approved! The strange thing is, a buddy of mine has also Sharepoint 2010 and he can select in the DropDown list 
-Current Item: -> Approval Status..

But the only things I can select are the following:

- Content Type
- Created By
- ID
- Modified
- Modified By
- Title

I don't understand what is going wrong! What am i forgetting to configure or bind or set? 
My situation:

[image: Picture from my situation]

His situation:
[image: Picture from his situation]

Comment: No one any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!

I have setup an test environment, Sharepoint 2013 on MS Server 2008R2 and installed Sharepoint Designer 2013.
When I now edit the default out of the box "Approval - Sharepoint 2010", if you enter the condition "if current item field equals value", you can now select "Approval Status"!!

So this means that it IS available after all! After a lot of trying, searching, this is the solution in a Sharepoint 2010 environment, installed on MS Server 2008R2:

1. Edit the (global or copied version if you want) workflow.
2. Add the condition "if current item field equals value" as a step.
3. Select from the item field: Content Type
4. Click on "equals" and change it to "not equals"
5. Then click on the condition and enter manually the following: 0;#Approved
6. Move the task "Start Approval Workflow Task..." up so it is a part of the condition "If..
   "
7. Add an Else condition
8. Enter here your custom action or log to show the user that the Task is not performed.
9. **Save** the workflow.

**We now have to manually edit the Workflow Rules file.**

1. In Sharepoint Designer 2010, click at the left side of the ribbon on "All Files".
2. - If you have created a custom workflow, you can find the "Workflow.xoml.rules" file, in the folder *Workflows/"Your custom workflow"/"CustomWorkflow.xoml.rules".*
   - If you are using the global, out of the box Workflow, you can find the .rules file in: *_catalogs/wfpub/Approval - SharePoint 2010/ReviewApproval_1033.xoml.rules*
3. Click on the file, then in the next screen click on "*Edit file*" under Customization.
   4.Search for the string "*ContentType*"
   5.When you have found the string, it looks a bit like this:

*ns1:String xmlns:ns1="clr-namespace:System;Assembly=mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">ContentType ns1:String*

(When you look a few lines below this line, you see your added condition 0;#Approved)!

6.Replace the string ContentType with: _ModerationStatus
7.Save the file!
8.Open in the current directory the "Workflow.xoml" file (this is the workflow itself)
9. Click on the Save button, it will give you a notice:

*A more recent version of _catalogs/wfpub/Approval - SharePoint 2010/ReviewApproval_1033.xoml.rules has been saved to the server by "user" on 1/5/2014 10:50 AM.*

*Do you want to replace this with your file?*

Click **NO**! (***Important, otherwise it will replace it with the default rules file, and nothing has changed!***)

1. Close Sharepoint Designer 2010, reopen SPD2010 and go to the workflow.
2. Edit the workflow and you'll see the following now:

*"If Current Item: equals 0;#Approved"*

The field Content Type is now gone! This is **correct** so don't worry!

1. Publish the workflow and you are done!
2. Check now on a library that has a link to the edited workflow, when you  start a new Workflow on a Approved-Major version of the document, what the outcome is:

The workflow is discarded because of the condition and nothing happened, so your document stays on the most recent Approved-Major version and is not published back to a previous version number!!

**Conclusion**: I think that the Sharepoint 2010 Designer, is missing that specific "Approval Status" field, but with the solution i have just given, you can solve this!